# Is it possible to use Host parameters while calling kubernetes service?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, keycloak, nginx-ingress

I have a frontend and backend application which is secured with a sso.

my nginx ingress controller:

```
- host: frontend.domain.com
  http:
    paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: frontend-service

- host: sso.domain.com
  http:
    paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: sso-service
```

If I call directly the domain, it works (Here will be the Host parameter correctly used by keycloak): {'active': true, JWT-token}

```
curl 
--location 
--request POST 'https://any.domain.com/auth/openid-connect/token/introspect' 
--header 'Host: sso.domain.com' 
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=abcd-1234' 
--data-urlencode 'client_id=backend' 
--data-urlencode 'token=JUST-A-TOKEN'
```

but if I call the kubernetes service, its not working: It is connecting like above and makes the request successfully but because the url is different (The Host parameter won't be triggered or called because I call service!?) keycloak will send {'active': false}

```
curl 
--location 
--request POST 'http://sso-service/auth/openid-connect/token/introspect' 
--header 'Host: sso.domain.com' 
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=abcd-1234' 
--data-urlencode 'client_id=backend' 
--data-urlencode 'token=JUST-A-TOKEN'
```

Maybe anyone has an idea or had the same issue? Why I cannot use the Host with kubernetes service together?

Comment: Hi Makiki, welcome to SO. I don't follow what you're asking; is it that you don't have a working DNS record for `sso.domain.com` and that's why you are trying to override the `Host:` header? Please be very specific about the problem you are experiencing, including the relevant error messages. Good luck

Comment: Hi mdaniel, I have a working DNS for the domains but I think, it does not make sense to call the domain itself in the Pod and thats why I am calling the service directly. But when I call the service (http://my-service/auth/introspect) in Pod, keycloak does not sends the valid token back because the token is generated on frontend with the (sso.domain.com). I am actually calling the same service on frontend too via nginx upstream/proxy_pass.

Comment: My question actually is, why I can make request with Host parameter when I call with a valid domain butt not with the service? How does the service resolve at the end? Does it actually look like http://10.0.10.40/auth/introspect (any IP)? Maybe because the service call does not resolve to the domain (sso.domain.com) but to IP?